# Need to generate random number according to the input i get

Tags: python

I made a dice game..
Im getting the number of participants who wish to play
Like this - no_of_players = int(input(‘No of players:’))

Each player has 2 dices,
If i got 4 players as the input, how can I generate 2 random numbers 1-7 for each?
 only need to generate numbers according to the number of players

Comment: The purpose of stackoverflow is to help you when you have a problem, not really code or you. Did you tried something ? What worked, what didn't ?

Comment: By generating 8 random numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop and then generate 2 dices per player

```
import numpy as np

no_of_players = int(input('No of players: '))

for i in range(no_of_players):
    # the high range is never included, so you need to put 7 instead of 6.
    player_roll = np.random.randint(low=1, high=7, size=2)
    print(f"Player{i+1} dice roll: {player_roll[0]}, {player_roll[1]}")


No of players: 3
Player1 dice roll: 5, 2
Player2 dice roll: 1, 1
Player3 dice roll: 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint

player_count = int(input("Player count : "))

for player in range(player_count):
    print(f"Player {player} : {randint(1, 7)}, {randint(1, 7)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```py
from random import choices

DIE_FACES = 6


def get_player_rolls(num_players: int,
                     dice_per_player: int) -> dict[int, list[int]]:
    rolls = choices(range(1, DIE_FACES + 1), k=num_players * dice_per_player)
    return {
        p + 1: rolls[p * dice_per_player:p * dice_per_player + dice_per_player]
        for p in range(num_players)
    }


def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")


def main() -> None:
    print("Hugo's Dice Game")
    print("================")
    num_players = get_int_input("Enter number of players: ")
    dice_per_player = get_int_input("Enter number of dice per player: ")
    player_rolls = get_player_rolls(num_players, dice_per_player)
    print(f"{player_rolls = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Hugo's Dice Game
================
Enter number of players: 4
Enter number of dice per player: 2
player_rolls = {1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 3], 3: [4, 5], 4: [2, 1]}
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Hugo's Dice Game
================
Enter number of players: 3
Enter number of dice per player: 3
player_rolls = {1: [1, 5, 6], 2: [3, 1, 3], 3: [1, 3, 4]}
```

Try it out [here](https://replit.com/@SashSinha1/ConsiderableMundaneElectricity#main.py).

Answer (score -1):

```py
from random import randint

a = randint(1,7)
b = randint(1,7)
```